# Custom Properties on PowerShell 3.0

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm very new to power shell but what I'm I doing wrong.

Here is my script

```
Write-Host "PowerShell Version = " ([string]$psversiontable.psversion) 
for($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++)    
{
    $failedObject = @{'IPAddress'='192.168.0.1';
                'Username'='someusername';
        'FailedAttempts'= 0;
                }

    $failedObject.FailedAttempts = 10

    Write-Host $failedObject.IPAddress
    Write-Host $failedObject.Username    
    Write-Host $faileObject.FailedAttempts
}
```

Here is the output

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> C:\PSScripts\pstest2.ps1
PowerShell Version =  3.0
192.168.0.1
someusername

192.168.0.1
someusername

192.168.0.1
someusername
```

I think I am having issue with adding custom properties to my object but not sure what I am doing wrong.  It appears to only happen for the FailedAttempts property and not for the Username or the IPAdress property.

Is this because it is an int property.  What am I doing wrong?  Eventually I will want to find an object based on IPAddress and Username and increment FailedAttempts by 1 or add object to an existing array based on IPAddress and Username...do you have easy code for that?

I guess my main question for now is why is the FailedAttempts not showing up in the Write-Host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on this line:

```
Write-Host $faileObject.FailedAttempts
```

Look closely.

Comment: I'm sorry as stated I'm new to PowerShell can you modify my script so that it will show the FailedAttempts during the output.  For some reason my current script just ignores it.

Comment: @DanP I added an example of property access.

Comment: Can you provide entire script in one code block...I am still having issues printing out the FailedAttempts property.

Comment: @DanP Done, fyi - you had a typo when printing FailedAttempts, which was why it wasn't returning anything. You still weren't actually creating a object, just a hash table but the typo was your real problem.

Comment: Thanks...I'm used to having a compiler tell me I had a typo :).  In regards to object vs hash table I'll have to look into just getting familar with PowerShell.  Eventually I'll want to put these "objects/hashtables" into an array and retrieve them based on ip and username and then increment the count...but that may be another question.  Sorry to post stupid typo question...but thanks again for spotting it.